# Spyder not launching in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

Several days ago, Spyder stopped running. I tried almost everything on forums. I desinstalled it and downloaded last version of anaconda package, but to no avail.

This is what the anaconda prompt shows me

[image: Anaconda prompt]

As I said, I tried uploading qt, PySide, and even tried to locate .spyder2 to erase it as is said in Anaconda webpage.
I really don't know what else to try

EDIT: Don't know if you need versions of anything, because as I said, it is the standard last version package available in Anaconda.

EDIT2: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please run these commands in the Anaconda prompt to see if they help: 1. `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 spyder`; 2. `activate py36`; 3. `spyder`.

Comment: Didn't work. It says no module named "PySide", and afterwards error because of no qt bindings could be found. More or less what was said without the environment

Comment: Did you install other software since the last time Spyder was working correctly?

Comment: Besides the fact that I had it configured so Spyder run updates authomatically, I don't know if this started failing before or after I cracked Office with KMSPico. I've tried with different versions, installing and uninstalling, trying to follow each error, but to no avail